# Grails 3 error "Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Tags: gradle, grails-3.0

When running command in my GRAILS 3.2.7 application folder:

```
grailsw generate-all com.mycmp.myapp.*
```

I get error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine.

I am on windows 10 x64 with Java 1.8.0 x64.
Looking on the net the JVM options for gradle should be added but no idea where this should be done.
Tried in gradle.properties to add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=524m
```

But no luck at all. Any hint?

This is the full error message:

> | Resolving Dependencies. Please wait... | Error Error initializing
>   classpath: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be
>   caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
>   unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>   the following process output to find out more:
>   ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Error: Could not create
>   the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
>   Program will exit.  (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that my JAVA_HOME was pointing to another path than the java folder in my PAT environment variable.
CHeck at a cmd window with

```
ECHO %JAVA_HOME%
ECHO %PATH%
```